# Unable to remove these characters from the data in a string in r

Tags: r, data-cleaning, tm

I am trying to remove the special character from the following string with the help of following code , but not getting the result :

library(tm)

```
v <- "rt shibxwarrior hodl  trust  processsome great things    horizon folks    shib \n\nshib shiba shibainu shibarâ€¦"

 t <- "[\n~@!#$%&*â€¦[]'=;]"

removespl_character <- function(x)gsub('t','',x)

cleanset_t <- tm_map(v,removespl_character)
```

Please help me on this.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the pattern to this :

```
 v <- "rt ~@!#$%&*â€¦[]'=; shibxwarrior[] hodl  trust  processsome great things    horizon folks    shib \n\nshib shiba shibainu shibarâ€¦"
t <- "[~@\\!#\n$%&\\*â€¦\\'=;]|\\]|\\["

v
gsub(pattern = t, replacement = "", x = v)
```

I copied your input :

```
v <- "rt shibxwarrior hodl  trust  processsome great things    horizon folks    shib \n\nshib shiba shibainu shibarâ€¦"
t <- "[~@\\!#\n$%&\\*â€¦\\'=;]|\\]|\\["

v
gsub(pattern = t, replacement = "", x = v)
```

Comment: why did you introduce : rt ~@!#$%&*â€¦[]'=; shibxwarrior[] in the given text, this is the actual text and special character from the text should be removed, it is showing some error.. please check.. thanks for the help

Comment: I've added the special character to be sure they are removed since you didn't have all of them in your example

Comment: have you tried removing it, as in the output it is showing following error :Error in UseMethod("inspect", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'inspect' applied to an object of class "character"